# Disable compiler-generated copy-assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, copy

When I'm writing a class (say `class nocopy`), is it possible to prevent the existence of the copy operator entirely? If I don't define one, and somebody else writes something like

```
nocopy A;
nocopy B;
A = B;
```

the compiler will auto-generate a definition. If I define one myself, I will prevent the compiler from auto-generating, but the code above will still be legal.

I want the code above to be illegal, and generate a compile time error. How do I do that?

Comment: The linked answers address *copy constructors* while the question asks about assignment operators.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You just declare a  copy constructor with `private` access specifier and not even define it.
Anyone trying to use it will get an compile error since it is declared `private`.

If someone uses it even indirectly, you will get a link error.

You can't do anything more than that in C++03.

However, In C++11 you can **[Explicitly delete special member functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions)**.

Eg:

```
struct NonCopyable {
    NonCopyable & operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable() = default;
};
```

Comment: One step further is to inherit `boost::noncopyable`

Comment: For Windows, see: [Explicitly Defaulted and Deleted Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx)  And the C++11 support matrix for VS2010-VS2013 [Support For C++11 Features (Modern C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

Comment: can i also static_assert that it has been deleted?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen yes, with `std::is_copy_assignable` from `<type_traits>`

Comment: Are you saying it is enough to declare the copy ctor private, to disable the compiler-generated assignment operator?

Answer (score 6):

The usual way is to declare the copy constructor and the assignment operator to be private, which causes compilation errors, like Als explained.

Deriving from `boost::noncopyable` will do this job for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you inherit from `boost::noncopyable` you will get a compile time error when the copy constructor is attempted. I have found that using this the error messages (with MSVC) are useless, since they generally don't point to the line that caused the error. The alternative is to declare a copy-constructor `private` and leave it undefined, or define it with a `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(false)`. If you are working with C++11 you can also `delete` your copy constructor:

```
class nocopy
{
    nocopy( nocopy const& ) = delete;
};
```